# Migration Hibernate 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers, hibernate-6.x

I try to migrate a SpringBoot application to SpringBoot 3. Sprinboot 3 use Hibernate 6.
My application refuse to start because of the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addJoins(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:206)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateSecondPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:409)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:86)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:129)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:92)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:329)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
... 110 common frames omitted
```

After digging in the Envers code it appear that the problem is located in the [org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadaGenerator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.1.5/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/configuration/internal/metadata/AuditMetadataGenerator.java) class.

At line 337, there is a condition that let a audited class be referenced during the `first pass` of envers .

```
if ( entity.isJoinAware() ) {
        final JoinAwarePersistentEntity joinAwareEntity = (JoinAwarePersistentEntity) entity;
        createJoins( persistentClass, joinAwareEntity, auditingData );
        addJoins( persistentClass, propertyMapper, auditingData, persistentClass.getEntityName(), mappingData, true );
}

private void createJoins(PersistentClass persistentClass, JoinAwarePersistentEntity entity, ClassAuditingData auditingData) {
    final Iterator<org.hibernate.mapping.Join> joins = persistentClass.getJoinIterator();
    final Map<org.hibernate.mapping.Join, Join> joinElements = new HashMap<>();
    entityJoins.put( persistentClass.getEntityName(), joinElements );
    ....
```

This is this list that is called during the `second pass` line 206.

```
while ( joins.hasNext() ) {
        final org.hibernate.mapping.Join join = joins.next();
        final Join entityJoin = entityJoins.get( entityName ).get( join );
```

Here `entityJoins.get(entityName)` return `null` for one of my entity.

This entity is correctly annotated with @Audited and extend from another Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@Audited
@DiscriminatorValue("DISCRIMINATOR")
public class A extends B {
   //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Audited
public abstract class B {
   //...
}
```

In my comprehension, specifying the Inheritance with a value of `InheritanceType.JOINED` make envers create a [JoinedSubclassPersistentEntity](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/boot/model/SubclassPersistentEntity.java) that itself inherit from [PersistentEntity](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/boot/model/PersistentEntity.java).

This `PersistentEntity` has a method :

```
public boolean isJoinAware() {
    return false;
}
```

that is overriden by it's children like [RootPersistentEntity](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/boot/model/RootPersistentEntity.java) by :

```
@Override
public boolean isJoinAware() {
    return true;
}
```

This override is not made by `JoinedSubclassPersistentEntity` which is the class generated when using Joined inheritence strategy.

This cause my entity to not be add to the `first pass` but still processed by the `second pass`.

So the question is ? Is it a bug in Envers ? Can i used Joined inheritence strategy with a @Audited class ?

It was working well in hibernate 5.6.

[Edit]:
I managed to reproduce the error with a simple test class :

```
@Entity
@Audited
@DiscriminatorValue("OPTION")
public class Child extends Parent{

    private String propA;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "recursive_children_child", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recursive_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    @NotAudited
    @OrderBy("propA DESC")
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "recursive_children_child", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recursive_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "child_id")})
    @NotAudited
    private Child recursiveChild;
    public Child(String propA) {
        this.propA = propA;
    }

    public Child() {

    }

    public String getPropA() {
        return propA;
    }

    public void setPropA(String propA) {
        this.propA = propA;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with the recursive relationship in the `Child` class. Ember try to audit the relationship despite the presence of `@Audited` annotation.

Link to a project that reproduce the bug => https://github.com/scandinave/envers6-migration-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem by reading the Jakarta Persistence Spec.

> The JoinTable annotation is used in the mapping of entity associations. **A JoinTable annotation is
> specified on the owning side of the association**

In my project there is a `@JoinTable` annotation on both side of the association. This was working before Hibernate 6, but not now. I just had to remove the @JoinTable not needed to solve the error.